# Using IP of visitors with API for displaying Flags of them

Tags: php, json, api, ip, decode

I wrote below PHP Code for getting IP of visitors and using API for showing the visitors country flags. This code worked on my hosting but suddenly after 2 month I saw it doesn't show the flags of visitors! I really don't know what happened! If someone knows please guide me, Thanks a lot

```
   <?php
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $json_data = file_get_contents("http://ip-api.com/json/$ip");
    $ip_data = json_decode($json_data, TRUE);
    if ($ip_data['status'] == 'success') {
        ?>



    <?php }
    ?>

    <?php
    $country= $ip_data['countryCode'];
    echo "<img src='http://b-c-e.us/country/images/$country.png' height='13' width='20'/>";

    ?>
```

Comment: b-c-e.us has deleted those images…?!

Comment: no, I could find the issue thanks for every help. "Usage limits Our system will automatically ban any IP addresses doing over 150 requests per minute. To unban your IP click here."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be this (taken from http://ip-api.com/docs/)

> Usage limits Our system will automatically ban any IP addresses doing
>   over 150 requests per minute. To unban your IP click here.
>
> You are free to use ip-api.com for non-commercial use. We do not allow
>   commercial use without prior approval.
>
> For commercial, unlimited use see our pro service.

Also at http://b-c-e.us/country/images/

Some of the images seem to be .jpg so you might want to cover that in the code.